# How to create managed Profile in Android

Tags: android, android-for-work, android-managed-profile

How to create managed profile in Android?

1. Restrict Wi-Fi.
2. Restrict camera, screen capture.
3. Wipe out data.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, Android offered a so-called `Device Admin` functionality. This allowed apps to change passcode and apply a couple of restrictions.

A 'Managed Profile' is a concept of a program formerly known as Android for Work. The idea there is that there are two parts of the OS on the device, and a 'Managed Profile' aka 'Work Profile' is a section that contains things managed by MDM.
Because of that, not all restrictions and features of Device Admin work. Specifically, you won't be able to fully restrict wifi access or 'wipe out data'. You could, however, delete the managed profile at will.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, check out [Android at work](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dpc/build-dpc)

This is the implementation of android in enterprise mobility management. This lets you to gain complete control over an android device, which can restrict wifi, screen capture & camera. This even allows you to disable mobile networks, disable data through mobile, wipe out data from the device and other high level controls.

Checkout [Managed-configurations](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html) and [Corporate owned single unit](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) details. They both gives you better control over the device, and both have their pros and cons.